# A question about notation in derivatives inn $\partial_{\bar{A}}L^I$

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, partial-derivative

In this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2332, when the authors say eq (2.17):

$$\partial_{\mu}L^I=\partial_{\bar{A}}L^I\partial_{\mu}\bar{z}^A+\partial_AL\partial_{\mu}z^A$$, does they mean by $\partial_{\bar{A}}L^I$ that it is $\partial L^I/\partial\bar{z}^{A}$? Or $\partial L^I/\partial \bar{A} $? I guess $A$ is not something you a derive over there, is it?

Comment: Im thinking It would be the former, they describe the fields in variable z with index A near the beginning of the paper